# Changing shapes of points in ggplot plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have made a visualisation using ggplot and plotly (see code below):

```
Figure1 <- ggplot(MergeAll, aes(theme_classic())) + 
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_call, y = Mean_11_1, color= "call"), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_sms, y = Mean_11_1,  color= "sms"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_call, y = Mean_05_2, color= "call"), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_sms, y = Mean_05_2,  color= "sms"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = total, y = Mean_11_1, color = "Mean_11_1"), na.rm = TRUE, se = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = total, y = Mean_05_2, color= "Mean_05_2"), na.rm = TRUE, se = FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 4000)) +
   labs(title = "Relationship between phone interaction (calls+SMS) and life satisfaction",
       subtitle = "Life satisfaction in the months may and november of 2010",
       caption = "Data from the Friends and Family Dataset.",
       tag = "Figure 1",
       x = "Telephone Interaction (call + text)",
       y = "Average Life satisfaction (5-point scale)",
       colour = "Legenda") +
   scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Call", "May 2010", "November 2010", "SMS")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", color = "darkgreen"))
ggplotly(Figure1, tooltip = c(hoverinfo = "count_call", "count_sms", "Mean_05_2", "Mean_11_1"))
```

This already took me forever and I am kind of happy with what it looks like now. However, I have been trying to change the shape of the data points based on Gender.

```
geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_call, y = Mean_11_1, color= "call", shape= "Gender"), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_sms, y = Mean_11_1,  color= "sms", shape = "Gender"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_call, y = Mean_05_2, color= "call", shape = "Gender"), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = count_sms, y = Mean_05_2,  color= "sms", shape = "Gender"), na.rm = TRUE) +
```

However, this does not work (no errror messages, it just looks weird.

```
head(MergeAll)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
# Groups:   participantID [3]
  participantID Mean_05_2 Mean_11_1 count_sms   n.x count_call   n.y Gender total
  <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <int> <int>      <int> <int> <fct>  <int>
1 sp10-01-05         6.11     NA           76    76        434   434 female  1020
2 sp10-01-05         6.11     NA           76    76        434   434 female  1020
3 sp10-01-06        NA         5.33       116   116        201   201 male     634
4 sp10-01-06        NA         5.33       116   116        201   201 male     634
5 sp10-01-07         5.78      6         3107  3107       1465  1465 male    9144
6 sp10-01-07         5.78      6         3107  3107       1465  1465 male    9144
```

Could someone maybe help me? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: you need to do shape = Gender, because it is supposed to go with female/male in the gender column

Comment: And it seems like your data is duplicated.. rows 1 and 2 are identical, and so are 3 and 4, 5 and 6.. did you merge it correctly?